# VsCode is not stopping on breakpoints - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

Brand new to flutter and I'm using VSCode as my IDE. However, I can't seem to get VSCode to call any of my breakpoints I place. I've tried normal breakpoints, Expression Breakpoints. None of them are even registering.

Everywhere online says to change the launch.json which I have done as show below

```
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Flutter",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "debug"
        },
    ]
```

However it didn't do anything. I'm using android studio's emulator and sometimes chrome; works on neither. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you can use the developer package to make breakpoints

```dart
import 'dart:developer';

void someFunction(double offset) {
  debugger(when: offset > 30.0);
  // ...
}
```

Look it in [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/code-debugging)

Comment: That looks better, and more versatile, then using VSCode's built in breakpoints anyway!

Comment: Yeah right, having to add an import (and hence change the code) to every file you want to set a breakpoint on is really better than just being able to add a breakpoint like in every IDE out there. Not. I'm hoping I will find an SO question about breakpoints in VSCode Dart that does not have this completely separate feature as the only and accepted answer. So far nothing. This is NOT getting breakpoints to work. What's next? Suggesting to log a message as an alternative to breakpoints working?

Answer (score 7):

I solved this issue by disabling `Dart: Preview Sdk Daps` in Settings. My Dart SDK was not linked to the remote repository and was outdated so this setting was not working properly. This is done with `"dart.previewSdkDaps": false`

```json
{
    "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "debug.toolBarLocation": "docked",
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "dart.previewSdkDaps": false
}
```

Comment: Wish there was an example of your "settings" for better context. :)

Comment: it worked for my problem, where the breakpoint didn't work only on some files in the bloc.